# Feedback on a page please?

Tags: forms, users, experience

I don't know if this is the right place to ask for feedback on something I'm working on but it'd be great if I could have your expert thoughts.

I drive people through PPC to the page below because I want to make contact with them and get their business.
What flaws do you see in the user experience that stops them from filling in the form?
http://www.responsewebrecruitment.co.uk/save-thousands-on-recruitment-care-worker/

Thank you!

Comment: You could reword the question to be about the amount of content on a page, or the options available to the user

Answer (score 1):

You should try to minimize effort put in by the customer by making the fields in your form drop-downs instead of input text, if there are a fixed set of values for answers.

Even better would be to expose options instead of hiding them in a dropdown (if they are few in number). eg.

[image: Courtesy: goodui.org]
*(Courtesy GoodUI.org)*

Even if they aren't, you could definitely offer suggestions as they type. This will help if there are multiple options to enter. eg.

[image: Like stackexchange does it..]

**Further resources**

GoodUI.org is a nice read for those trying to make forms better.

Answer (score 0):

first impression is that there is far too much text on the page.
the header is long, and so are all the sentences - ask a short question and answer with a short reply.
i would ask for fewer details - anything you can ask over the phone or email doens't have to be a field - because every additional field lowers the response rate. some of the questions are long and not straight forward - and can also lead to a discussion you should not miss (how fast are you looking to recruit - why so long/short term? what is the buisness necessity - start a good sales conversation).
the bottom text is too thin and pale - make it bigger/bolder/change color to a more readble one.
hope it helped :)